# How do I get a new list with mapped keys if exist else external key?

Tags: scala

input:

```
type DeviceType = Any
val rh: Map[(String, String), String] = Map(("ss", "ex-ss") -> "MobileType", ("ud", "ex-ud") -> "DesktopType")
val lh: Map[String, DeviceType] = Map("ex-ss" -> 1, "ex-ud" -> "A@F4CC", "ex-zip" -> 30052)
```

**Expected output:** 
     val res:Map[String, DeviceType] = Map("ss" -> 1, "ud" -> "A@F4CC", "ex-zip" -> 30052)

Comment: Can you add more explanation as to what you are trying to perform?

Comment: basically you loop thru "lh" list and check whether "lh.key" exist in "rh.key" i.e. 2nd element of tuple, if exist then replace "lh.key" with mapped key from "rh" list i.e. 1st element of tuple, else keep the same key from "lh"

Comment: Is it guaranteed that keys of lh will be unique in rh?

Comment: yes, lh.keys will be unique in rh.keys

Answer (score 2):

So, basically you would need to create one more map to store connection between the tuples, from `rh` map.

Please, see code below for more details:

```
// Create device synonyms index, for instance: "ex-ss" -> "ss"
val deviceSynonyms: Map[String, String] = rh.keys.map(_.swap).toMap
val res: Map[String, DeviceType] = lh.map {
    case (deviceName, deviceType) => deviceSynonyms.getOrElse(deviceName, deviceName) -> deviceType
}
```

Which will produce desired result:

```
Map(ss -> 1, ud -> A@F4CC, ex-zip -> 30052)
```

Comment: all you need - val deviceSynonyms: Map[String, String] = rh.keys.map(_.swap).toMap

Comment: @ASD Yeah, thanks - I wanted to created more general index, then just for this case. I fixed and left what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is :

```
type DeviceType = Any
val rh: Map[(String, String), String] = Map(("ss", "ex-ss") -> "MobileType", ("ud", "ex-ud") -> "DesktopType")
val lh: Map[String, DeviceType] = Map("ex-ss" -> 1, "ex-ud" -> "A@F4CC", "ex-zip" -> 30052)
val rhKeySet = rh.keySet

val res: Map[String, DeviceType] = lh.map {
    case (k,v) =>
      if (rh.exists(_._1._2 == k)) {
        val res = rhKeySet.filter(_._2 == k).head
        res._1 -> v
      }else{
        k -> v
      }
  }
```

The output:

```
Map(ss -> 1, ud -> A@F4CC, ex-zip -> 30052)
```

Let me know if it helps!!